# Array contains more values than the db

Tags: php

I'm having trouble trying to work out the best way to do this, my code:

```
$purch = DB::getInstance()->select("SELECT * FROM `purchased`");

foreach($a as $val) {
    foreach($purch as $v) {
        $v['purchased_sape_ref_id']; // CONTAINS THE ID FROM THE DB //
        $val; // CONTAINS THE ID IN THE ARRAY //
        if (in_array($v, $val)) {
            echo "This id is in the $a array: " . $v['purchased_sape_ref_id'];
        } else {
            echo "This id is not in the $a array: " . $v['purchased_sape_ref_id'];
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `$a` is an array, I have already filed it with IDs (90 in total). The mysql query using `$v` contains 87 values, so the array `$a` contains 3 more values than `$v` (which is being pulled from the database)

What should I do to display the 3 additional values?

Comment: While looping through if the value is `!in-array($needle, $haystack)` then add it to another array `$notInArray = [];`

`if(!in_array($v, $a)) $notInArray[] = $v;` Now you have an array of numbers that are not in the original array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution using [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$diff = array_diff($a, array_column($purch, 'purchased_sape_ref_id'));
```

Now you can output all values from `$a` as existing in `$a` :) and you can output all values from `$diff` as not existing in `$a`.

[`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) gives you all values (as array) from first array which are not on the second array. With [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) you can directly access a column of your array. So you can get an array with all values of `$purch` on column `purchased_sape_ref_id`.

---

**Demo (http://ideone.com/2azqOd):**

```
<?php
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$purch = [
    ['test_col' => 'hello', 'purchased_sape_ref_id' => 1],
    ['test_col' => 'world', 'purchased_sape_ref_id' => 2],
    ['test_col' => 'stack', 'purchased_sape_ref_id' => 3]
];

$diff = array_diff($a, array_column($purch, 'purchased_sape_ref_id'));

foreach ($a as $a_value) {
    if (!in_array($a_value, $diff)) {
        echo 'This id is in the $a array: '.$a_value."\n";
    } else {
        echo 'This id is not in the $a array: '.$a_value."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys that helped a lot :)